# Ajax not loading in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

Here is the script. It works fine in all other browsers, so I thought it was a cache problem but not really. I have been banging my head for hours and nothing is working.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});

$("#send").live('click', function () {
    console.log("AAAAA");
    $("#loader").show();
    $form = $('#reservationForm');

    $inputs = $form.find('input[name^="entry"]'),
    serializedData = $('#reservationForm :input[name^="entry"]').serialize();

    console.log(serializedData);
    serializedData += "&pageNumber=0&backupCache=1&submit=Submit";

    // fire off the request to /form.php
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=d",
        // url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=d;ifq",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData,
        // callback handler that will be called on success
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
            $("#loader").hide();
            document.getElementById('error<?php echo"$uname";?>').innerHTML = error;
            $("#success").fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#success").fadeOut();
            }, 5000);
        },
        // callback handler that will be called on error
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // log the error to the console
            console.log("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert('Due to an unknown error, your form was not submitted, please resubmit it or try later.');
        },
        // callback handler that will be called on completion
        // which means, either on success or error
        complete: function () {
            // enable the inputs
            $inputs.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: i've made your javascript readable and removed missplaced "

Comment: may consider trying the code the way i edited it.

Comment: you could post your HTML code

Comment: Is the live event fired in IE ? Maybe crossdomain thing around ?

Answer (score 2):

console.log is available after you open Developer Tools (F12 to open) in IE. Try turning it on or use an alert instead in your code.
or use a try catch;

```
try{
    console.log('worked')
}
catch(err){
}
```

And You might want to check if your event variable is undefined:

```
event= event || window.event;
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Yep, `console.log` breaks your javascript in IE. Another alternative is to use something like the script in H5BP (https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/js/plugins.js), which defines the method in browsers that don't have it as a noop, so that doesn't cause errors.

Comment: A little example of how to use the plugin js would be of great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the script you are not adding the "event" declaration in the handler:

```
$("#send").live('click', function () {
```

should be:

```
$("#send").live('click', function (e) {
```

And at the end of the script there is a reference for the variable event:

```
 // prevent default posting of form
event.preventDefault();
```

I think that IE doesn't have a 'preventDefualt' function in the global event object (which you are referencing): this function is added to the "e" event object passed by jQuery. Any way, it should fail too in all other browsers with a "event is not defined". Try this too:

```
 // prevent default posting of form
e.preventDefault();
```

An additional note: jQuery team currently discourage the use of the "live" event binding function, instead you should use the equivalent form of the "on" function.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't understand the content type of response in ajax. So put your dataType value in the request and it should work. 
for e.g. -

```
dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml"
```